# http post authentication failure 403

Tags: android, post

I am trying to call a https post api from android app. It is giving 403 permission denied error. But the api works fine when called from postman or CURL in windows cmd. 
In android i have tried Volley and OkHttpClient but the response from both is same.I am attaching codes for both libraries. Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

- Volley

  ```
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
      String url = "https://xxxxx.com/api.php";
      StringRequest MyStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(String response) {
              // Do something with the response.
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() { 
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          }
      }) {
          protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
              Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
              MyData.put("content1", "xyz"); 
              MyData.put("content2", "xyz"); 
              return MyData;
          }
      }; queue.add(MyStringRequest);
  ```
- OkHttpClient

  ```
          OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
          RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                  .add("content1", "xyz")
                  .add("content1", "xyz")
                  .build();
          okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                  .url(url)
                  .post(formBody)
                  .build();
          try {
              okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
              // Do something with the response.
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

make sure oyu have the correct content type in the header. for instance in Volley

```
@Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
                params.put("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 


                return params;  
        }
```